# Corregir error en mi función de WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Estoy intentado crear una función de WP que colocaré en un tema. Se trata de una función que consiste en que el primer inicio de sesión de un usuario la función tomará los datos del usuario y los mandará a una URL. Lo que sucede es que coloco mi código y la web se cae (no carga) y no puedo analizar el problema porque el sitio web tiene un par de visitas y está siendo supervisada.

Está es mi función:

```html
<?php
function shapeSpace_first_user_login($user_login, $user) {
 $new_user = get_user_meta($user->ID, '_new_user', true);
 if ($new_user) {
  update_user_meta($user->ID, '_new_user', '0');

  global $current_user
  get_currentuserinfo();
  $titulo = $current_user->title;
  $nombre = $current_user->user_firstname;
  $apellido = $current_user->user_lastname;
  $institucion = $current_user->institution;
  $direccion = $current_user->addr1;
  $ciudad = $current_user->city;
  $pais = $current_user->country;
  $correo = $current_user->user_email;
  $correo_anterior = $correo;
  $contrasena = $current_user->password; // ¿La contraseña está encriptada?

  if (empty($titulo) || empty($institucion) || empty($city)) {
    $titulo = "Mr";
    $institucion = "Unknown institution";
    $ciudad = "Unknown city";
  }

  $url_registro = "http://isha2017.mundodecongresos.com/add_registered_user.asp?title=" .$title. "&first_name=" .$nombre. "&&last_name=" .$apellido. "&institution=" .$institucion. "&address=" .$direccion. "&city=" .$ciudad. "&country=" .pais. "&email=" .$correo. "&password=" .contrasena. "&previous_email=" .$correo_anterior.;
  $url_acceso = "http://isha2017.mundodecongresos.com/login_integration.asp?email=" .$correo. "&password=" .$contrasena.;

?>

  <form action="<?php echo $url_registro ?>" name="enviar_usuario">
  </form>

  <form action="<?php echo $url_acceso ?>" name="login_usuario">
  </form>

  <script>
  document.enviar_usuario.submit();
  document.login_usuario.submit();
  </script>

<?php
 }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'shapeSpace_first_user_login', 10, 2);
?>
```

Cualquier sugerencia es agradecida.

Comment: Yo creo que además de lo que te dice @Jorius, al final del proceso de registro ocurre una redirección mediante un comando `header`, pero si ya escribiste HTML, no puede hacer esa redirección.

Comment: Hay otro error aquí: `"&&last_name="` @amenadiel Wordpress tiene filtros para redirección sin necesidad de que el programador redirija usando header. Aunque creo que se trata de enviar los datos del nuevo usuario a otra parte, sin que el usuario se entere. Para esto existe: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano, ví ese código ayer, pero no me convencía y no lo entendí muy bien. Lo utilizaré como un plan B.

Comment: @América, te invito a que _una vez encuentres una solución_ puedas publicar una nueva respuesta para responder tu propia pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta un punto y coma ( **;** ) en tu variable:

```
global $current_user; //
```

También te sobra un punto ( **.** ) de concatenación en tus variable:

```
// Al final de estas líneas hay un punto (.) antes del punto y coma (;) el cual te sobra
$url_registro = "http://isha2017.mundodecongresos.com/add_registered_user.asp?title=" .$title. "&first_name=" .$nombre. "&&last_name=" .$apellido. "&institution=" .$institucion. "&address=" .$direccion. "&city=" .$ciudad. "&country=" .pais. "&email=" .$correo. "&password=" .contrasena. "&previous_email=" .$correo_anterior;
$url_acceso = "http://isha2017.mundodecongresos.com/login_integration.asp?email=" .$correo. "&password=" .$contrasena;
```

Lo cual te puede estar causando un `error 500` y por eso se te cae la web

Te recomiendo hacer uso de un editor de texto y/o IDE que pueda validar correctamente la sintáxis de tu código, en mi caso, yo uso [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) que trae soporte para `PHP` y muchos otros lenguajes, así te evitarás estos simples pero grandes dolores de cabeza, saludos!

Comment: Gracias Jorius, he descargado el programan y estoy viendo el código para aplicar las correciones.

Answer (score 0):

Nuevamente te agradezco Jorius he aplicado tus correciones, agregado otra función complementaria e imprimiendo el código de JS que era otra de las causas del problema. Ahora el código no genera ese error 500. Dejo el código a continuación:

```html
<?php

function shapeSpace_register_add_meta($user_id) {
 add_user_meta($user_id, '_new_user', '1');
}
add_action('user_register', 'shapeSpace_register_add_meta');

function shapeSpace_first_user_login($user_login, $user) {
 $new_user = get_user_meta($user->ID, '_new_user', true);
 if ($new_user) {
  update_user_meta($user->ID, '_new_user', '0');

  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  $titulo = $current_user->title;
  $nombre = $current_user->user_firstname;
  $apellido = $current_user->user_lastname;
  $institucion = $current_user->institution;
  $direccion = $current_user->addr1;
  $ciudad = $current_user->city;
  $pais = $current_user->country;
  $correo = $current_user->user_email;
  $correo_anterior = $correo;
  $contrasena = $current_user->password; // ¿La contraseña está encriptada?

  if (empty($titulo) || empty($institucion) || empty($city)) {
    $titulo = "Mr";
    $institucion = "Unknown institution";
    $ciudad = "Unknown city";
  }

  $url_registro = "http://isha2017.mundodecongresos.com/add_registered_user.asp?title=" .$title. "&first_name=" .$nombre. "&&last_name=" .$apellido. "&institution=" .$institucion. "&address=" .$direccion. "&city=" .$ciudad. "&country=" .pais. "&email=" .$correo. "&password=" .contrasena. "&previous_email=" .$correo_anterior;
  $url_acceso = "http://isha2017.mundodecongresos.com/login_integration.asp?email=" .$correo. "&password=" .$contrasena;

  echo "<form action='" .$url_registro. "' name='enviar_usuario'></form>";
  echo "<form action='" .$url_acceso. "' name='login_usuario'></form>";
  echo "<script> document.enviar_usuario.submit(); document.login_usuario.submit();</script>";

 }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'shapeSpace_first_user_login', 10, 2);
?>
```